# Printing "Hello World" to the terminal takes a very long time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, build

I am just getting started in C# (and coding in general), following a very basic setup tutorial on  [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N775KsWQVkw). I am trying to run the simple bit of code generated from clicking **Terminal>New Terminal:**

```
using System;

namespace Program1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this should run just about instantly (it runs perfectly for the tutorial instructor).

I Also get the following problem (CS0579) (now resolved thanks to a comment):

> Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'

The file with this problem looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1", FrameworkDisplayName = "")]
```

The launch.json file has not been altered from the auto-generated file:

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Program1.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am running VSCode 1.47.2 and .NET Core SDK 3.1.302

Comment: You shouldn't be defining that attribute like that manually. If you have it in a file you should remove the line. The SDK automatically adds it, hence the duplicate

Comment: Thanks for your comment, like I said I'm completely new to this stuff. I haven't added any code (everything above is the auto-generated code). Are you saying I should remove [assembly: global::.... ?

Comment: Yes remove that. It's not going to impact your startup time, it's just wrong

Comment: Which launch config are you using. If you are using attach then yeah it will take a long time until you pick a process id to attach to, then it has to actually attach to it. If it’s the launch request then your culprit is most likely in your build preLaunchTask

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what the problem was!

Answer (score 1):

If you've just started this project, and all it consists of is the above code, I'd recommend closing visual studio, deleting the project folder, and starting over.  Seems like something got messed up and you're going to take a lot longer figuring out what it was than just starting over.

I know that sounds like the lazy way to do it, but with just a short 'hello world' program, you shouldn't need to take hours debugging it.  Just start over.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This was the first step I took and the problem persists.